# WCF REST Service POST returns 404 Not Found on IIS

Tags: wcf, post, iis-8

I have a WCF service created with VS2012 on Win8. If I start the service via VS (localhost:port) I'm able to do GET's and POST's. When I deploy to IIS on the same machine only GET works. The POST return 404 Not Found. I've tried deploying directly to IIS by creating an application off of my Default Web Site as well as using VS Publish.

POST URL: http://www.server.com/RestService/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth

POST Request Header: contents of PostData.xml below

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- Service Endpoints -->
          <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
          <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceImplEndpointBehavior">
              <!-- Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
                   identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity automatically. -->
          </endpoint>
       </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestServiceImplEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>

    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" 
                        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                        initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

iRestServerImpl.cs:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace RestService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "auth")]
        ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData);

    }
}
```

RestServiceImpl.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestService.RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" %>
```

RestServiceImpl.svc.cs

```
namespace RestService
{
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestServiceImpl Members

        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        public ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData)
        {
            // Call BLL here
            var data = rData.details.Split('|');
            var response = new ResponseData
                               {
                                   Name = data[0],
                                   Age = data[1],
                                   Exp = data[2],
                                   Technology = data[3]
                               };

            return response;
        }

        #endregion




    }
}
```

RequestData.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace RestService
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer")]
    public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ResponseData.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace RestService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Exp { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Technology { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PostData.xml

```
<RequestData xmlns="http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer">
  <details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details>
</RequestData>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. IIS Request Filtering for the application had POST set to not allowed.

Comment: How did you do it? Where did you fix it?

Comment: Not quite the same, I just had to add POST, since there was nothing there. On to the next error

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for POST and GET, though I have VS 2010 and IIS 7, but I see no problem in that. I published service as an application (POSTDataIssue) under a website. 
I used fiddler to first test GET request (URL - http://localhost:82/POSTDataIssue/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/5) and it gave expected result.

Then I tried POST with following content to the URL      http://localhost:82/POSTDataIssue/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth-

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:82
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 110


<RequestData xmlns="http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer">
 <details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details>
</RequestData>



 Response 
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Length: 218
 Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2013 02:34:58 GMT

 <ResponseData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Age>29</Age><Exp>7 Years</Exp><Name>Ashu</Name><Technology>.NET</Technology></ResponseData>
```

Comment: What was the response you received from the POST?